# Latest available PHP version for Linux not sufficient for Passport

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

I want to install Passport for my API, and when I type `composer require laravel/passport`, I get the error:

> [...] requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.27) does not satisfy that requirement.

The problem is, I have done an `apt-get upgrade` and it seems that I have the latest version of PHP for Linux (PHP 7.0.27). I am on Debian.

What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i suggest installing Xampp for Linux their are 2 packages on their site, so there is 1 that you might be interested in.

Comment: You'll have to find an alternate way to install 7.1.3. There are some instructions [here](http://blog.programster.org/debian-8-install-php-7-1) and [here](https://www.colinodell.com/blog/201612/installing-php-71) which may help, or google for others. Or you can compile it yourself.

Comment: @noobie-php I am already using XAMPP for Linux, and apparently [for the latest version it is PHP 7.2.4](https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/download.html#download-linux), but I don't think that's the version used by Composer (I assume it uses the CLI version).

Comment: use homestead. Technically it would be better in long term.

Comment: just install a newer version from https://deb.sury.org/